# How can I find regional translations of built-in SharePoint list names?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, translation

There are `PublishingWeb.PagesList` and `PublishingWeb.PagesListName` properties, but other list's urls also vary by site language. Those that I found are translated are:

- Documents
- Images
- Pages
- Workflow Tasks

There is additional API in SP2010, but how can I handle this in 2007?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This data is available with internal methods. So I have an invoke helper method:

```
[NotNull]
public static T Call<T>([CanBeNull] ref T cachedInvoker, [NotNull] Type subject, [NotNull] string methodName) where T : class
{
    if (cachedInvoker == null)
    {
        var method = subject.GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        cachedInvoker = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(T), method) as T;
        if (cachedInvoker == null)
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Unable to create invoker for [{0}].[{1}].", subject, methodName));
    }
    return cachedInvoker;
}
```

And then I get the data:

```
[NotNull]
public static SPFolder Documents([NotNull] this PublishingWeb web)
{
    return web.Lists[web.GetDocumentsListId()].RootFolder;
}

[NotNull]
public static string GetDocumentsListName([NotNull] this PublishingWeb web)
{
    return web.Lists[web.GetDocumentsListId()].Title;
}

private static Func<PublishingWeb, Guid> getDocumentsListIdInvoker;

[NotNull]
public static Guid GetDocumentsListId([NotNull] this PublishingWeb web)
{
    return
        Internal.Call(ref getDocumentsListIdInvoker, typeof (PublishingWeb), 
            "get_DocumentsListId")(web);
}

[NotNull]
public static string GetImagesListName([NotNull] this PublishingWeb web)
{
    return web.Lists[web.GetImagesListId()].Title;
}

private static Func<PublishingWeb, Guid> getImagesListIdInvoker;

[NotNull]
public static Guid GetImagesListId([NotNull] this PublishingWeb web)
{
    return
        Internal.Call(ref getImagesListIdInvoker, typeof(PublishingWeb), 
        "get_ImagesListId")(web);
}
```